# Difference between "be promoted soon" and "soon be promoted"?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

> 1. You have done well and you will **be promoted soon**.
> 2. You have done well and you will **soon be promoted**.

What's the difference? Is one of them grammatically wrong?

---

EDIT: I asked one of my friends and he gave me a vague theory that **adverbs of time should come before the verb if they occur before it**. In this example, the time "soon" should come before "be promoted" because ***the time which is appropriate for his promotion*** would come before ***his manager signs his promotion***.

If anyone has ever heard of such a rule then kindly enlighten me.

Comment: Also OK: "soon you will be promoted"  and even "you soon will be promoted" or "you will be soon promoted".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There *is* a difference of meaning. 
"You will be promoted soon" tells when you will be promoted. It's primarily a comment about your prospects.
"You will soon be promoted" tells what will happen soon. It's a comment on the process which results from you working hard.

Of course, if the words are said to you in either form, you'd be pleased, but I think the first sentence, with its emphasis on promotion, is slightly more encouraging.

Answer (score 2):

The two mean exactly the same thing and are both grammatically correct. *Soon* is a modifier of *be promoted*, so it can fit either before or after. Here, there is no confusion if *soon* is used before *be promoted*  because the phrase stands alone in its containing clause (*you will soon be promoted*).

Comment: "Soon" is an adverb modifying the verb "will be." "Promoted" is a participle acting as predicate adjective.